# How to animate "visibility: hidden"?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, visibility

here is my problem... Can you help me please?

```
$(".button").hover(function(){
  $('.class').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "hidden"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1200);
},function(){
  $('.class').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1200);
});
```

It only animates when it is appearing. :-(

Comment: Why the heck are you doing this with jquery? This is a simple CSS transition. Zero reason to use jquery for a button hover.

Comment: The answers to this question make it very obvious that we should expect to see a LOT of inefficient jQuery in the wild. @AmmarCSE's answer is what you want in production (though the others may teach you something about jQuery behaviour).

Comment: @holdenweb No, in production your will want a CSS based solution, as showcased in my answer.

Comment: Ah, good call, though in fairness your answer wasn't posted at the time. What I *should* have said is "look quite hard for jQuery methods to do what you want before inventing your own" (this improves your jQuery skills too). You are quite correct to suggest a declarative solution based on CSS which doesn't involve Javascript at all. Thanks

Comment: I overlooked it, too: OP wants to fadein/out a different element `.class` when hovering `.button`.

Comment: @connexo yep, I edited my answer to show how it can be done with transitions still, in a way that is probably cleaner, better separated and more efficient than using jquery functions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(".button").hover(function(){
  $('.class').css("opacity", "1.0").animate({opacity: 0}, 1200, function(){
    $('.class').css("visibility", "hidden");
});
},function(){
  $('.class').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1200);
});
```

However, this is not the best option to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. You can use instead the methods with those names that jQuery provide, or better, use CSS transitions in case you can.

Answer (score 6):

The visibility property in CSS is Boolean, either on or off.

In order to any animation to work, whether it's done with keyframes, transitions or jquery, the start point and end point of the property value set need to broken down into a set of steps, with a greater number of steps resulting in a smoother animation.

For a simple effect like this, a [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) is best, [please see the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzjepj1w/7/). Use javascript just to add / remove classes that trigger the transition

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.show-me {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You set the transition property defining the property to transition, then the length, the ease function to use (which describes changes to the rate at which the animation has effect). You also need to define the start point and end point for your animated property as you can see with the two opacity values.

For the record - a keyframe is appropriate if your effect was more complex, like wanting one property to have fully animated half way through and then to animate back while another to take the full time, or for oscillations; and JQuery animate provides an easy way to act on the conclusion of an animation which is also sometimes necessary.

Comment: I overlooked it, too: OP wants to fadein/out a different element `.class` when hovering `.button`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").hover(function(){
    $('.class').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate( //start off from opacity 1 and visibile
        {opacity: 0}, //then animate opacity to 0
        1200, 
        function(){ //this will be run after the animation is completed
            $(this).css({
                visiblity:"hidden" //so it will be hidden only after the animation has completed
            });
        }
    );
},function(){
  $('.class').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
$(".button").hover(function(){
  $('.class').fadeOut(1200);
},function(){
  $('.class').fadeIn(1200);
});
```

You can pass in `duration` which should achieve your goals

Comment: that is for display:none vs display:block

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is removed before it cam animate.  You would need to animate the fade out first, then apply `visibility: hidden` after the animation is complete.

There are a couple of ways to do this:  The browser raises an event `animationend` (this is prexied for various browsers -- see here for more info) or you can use a better animation library than jQuery animate (like Green Sock TweenLite -- http://greensock.com/tweenlite) to handle your animation, which makes it trivial to run code at the end of the animation.