# Animated Dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

Trying to get a dropdown menu going for my 6th project using Ruby on Rails. Kinda lost here, I've tried some codes from different sources scattered online, but I've had no success (not even close via copy/paste).

My current code:

```
.dropdown {
visibility: none; 
}

.dropdown:hover {
transition-timing-function: ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

Can't seem to get the hover function working on top of the dropdown one for the life of me. 
How would you recommend I get these ease-out/fade-in animations going?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate "visibility: hidden"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694316/how-to-animate-visibility-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

Your visibility is set to none. And in your hover state you are just telling how you want the transition to unfold, but not what you want it to transition to... for eks. tell it to go from visibility: hidden to visibility: visible